# Putting Doorway into Loadbearing Wall

Tags: framing

I would like to put a doorway into a loadbearing wall by removing 1 stud.  My measurements between what would be the remaining studs is 30.5 inches.  I was hoping to do a header using header hangers into what would be king studs (the remaining studs), to avoid taking up door width with jack studs.  From the chart in the link below, it indicates that would be acceptable as a replacement of two jack studs (one on each side).  However, as I read the chart, I am supposed to have two jacks on each side.

This doorway would be on the first floor of a two story house which I believe is 36' feet wide.

I just want to confirm that I cannot use header hangers instead of jacks before I consider whether a much smaller door is worth it or if I ditch the idea entirely.

[Proper size of header to support new door in load bearing wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/42744/proper-size-of-header-to-support-new-door-in-load-bearing-wall)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to compromise the proper installation of the appropriate width door just because you just want to remove one stud. Do it right and remove two studs if necessary and install additional king studs and jack studs compatible with the rough opening. Done properly the header can span the jack studs and carry the load like it is supposed to. No metal hanger brackets are needed if this is done the correct way.

The only real additional effort involved with doing it right is that you will have to open up a bit more of the wall from one side. And that leads to a bit more drywall work to patch it back up --- that is unless of course the wall was already open from one side.

Comment: Thank you, you confirmed my suspicions.  The wall is open and I was making the consideration before closing it in.  With the cost of the other projects right now better just to close it up.  I was getting ahead of myself not really thinking about contractors and that it would require a permit.  Appreciate your response.